# MongoDB driver extension (php_mongodb.dll)) not found by PHP v7.2.5

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to add MongoDB extension to the PHP and use it with Laravel 5.6. 
I know that I should download the `dll` file from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) and copy it in the ext folder inside PHP and add `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to my `php.ini` file. But I face this warning when I do like what I said:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll'
>   (tried: C:\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.), C:\php\ext\php_php_mongodb.dll.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I'm a windows 10 user and my PHP version is 7.2.5.

Is it effect on MongoDB usage or It's ignorable and I can overtake it?

**Update:**

I also tested `extension=php_mongodb.dll` like `extension=php_mongodb`, `extension=mongodb.dll`, `extension=php_mongodb.dll` and extension=mongodb too.

And I copied the `php_mongodb.dll` to the `C:\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll`.

Comment: C:\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll is it there?

Comment: @flakerimi Yes of course!

Comment: Is mongodb driver working, because is just warning so you can ignore it if it works.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/677#issuecomment-347272819